# iOS using an external subscription service

Tags: ios, external, subscription

I need some advice on subscription-based apps for iOS. I have an app that will only work/function when you are a premium subscriber to a service I offer (i.e. the first view on my app is a login screen, all subscribers have a login account). Subscribers can only subscribe to my service via my website, there is no in-app purchasing in my app (& there are no links to my site via the app), all subscribers are 100% from my site.

I know there was a change in Apple's policy regarding subscriptions back in june 2011. (http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/06/apple-quietly-drops-special-subscription-requirements-for-ios-apps.ars).

So I would like to know if you think this type of app would be accepted/rejected?

I've emailed Apple, but still awaiting a response after 4 days.

Note, my subscription policy is very much like the Spotify app.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on case by case. Do you allow them to register for a free account? Say limited account access? The big thing is allowing them to change subscriptions in-app. That would be a very big no-no. I think if you are up front, and limit how much interaction they have with the money side of things, you should be able to slip under the radar. There are plenty of SaS models in the store that aren't' being banned, so you don't have too much to worry about. So long as you aren't selling music or magazines, you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for your input Bill, my thoughts exactly. If I get a response from Apple I will post it here.

Comment: No problem. If it was me, I'd submit and hope to fly under the radar. If it is work for someone else that can't afford to get kicked out later or won't have time to update later, then better to wait. But they aren't usually that speedy getting back to devs.